# Horizontal alignment in multicols

Tags: align, amsmath, enumerate, multicol

I was working with math equations in `multicols`, but the equations don't seem to align (i.e. (a), (c) and (e) do not horizontally align). Is there any easy workaround for this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.55in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item 
Sketch the graph of each function.
    \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $y=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2-5$
        \item $y=-9|x+1|$
        \item $y=\left(\dfrac{5}{3}x^3\right)^3+2$
        \item $y=4+2\sqrt{x-3}$
        \item $y=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$
        \item $y=\llbracket|x|-4 \rrbracket$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand; they look aligned to me.  Which of them do you think is out of position?

Comment: Item (c) is not aligned with (a) and (e).

Comment: It is because of the extra height in (c).  You could add a common strut to each item.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: The easiest fix is probably to use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)` instead of `\left(` and `\right)`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Before piling up a bunch of questions, consider giving feedback to the users who answered and try to accept one of the answers then.

Answer (score 2):

The `tasks` package is much simpler to use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,lettersize]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.55in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem, tasks}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]), label-offset = 1em, column-sep = 1.5em}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
Sketch the graph of each function.

 \begin{tasks}[](3)
        \task $y=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2-5$
        \task $y=-9|x+1|$
        \task $y=\left(\dfrac{5}{3}x^3\right)^3+2$
        \task $y=4+2\sqrt{x-3}$
        \task $y=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$
        \task $y=\llbracket|x|-4 \rrbracket$
    \end{tasks}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]